# htaccess regex matching path containing 'foo' without 'bar' in it

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to block some URL via a `.htaccess` file with `RedirectMatch 403`.

Anything that contains `YES` should be matched only if `NO` is not in the URL too. Some examples of matching URLs or not:

- /dir/`YES`/ -> yes
- /`YES`/file.ext -> yes
- /dir/`NO`/dir/`YES`/file.ext -> no
- /`NO`/dir/dir/`YES`/file.ext -> no

Also there is an unknown number of `dir` between `/YES` and `/NO`.

I've tried various *lookbehind* and patterns like:

- `(?<!themes/)(vendor)`
- `(?<=[^themes])(/vendor)`
- `(?<![themes/])(/|/[^themes]+/)vendor(/|$)`

But am struggling to get anything working and wondering if this is actually a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you're patterns aren't working:

```
(?<!themes/)(vendor)
```

Will only discard the match if `themes/` is immediately to the left of `vendor`. Lookbehinds do not traverse the entire string automtically.

```
(?<=[^themes])(/vendor)
```

Character classes don't work like this. `[^themes]` matches a single character that is not one of `e`, `h`, `m`, `s` or `t`.

What you would want is `(?<!themes.*/)(vendor)` but only .NET allows lookbehinds of arbitrary length.

The trick is to start at the beginning and make sure that there is no `NO` on the way to `YES` using lookaheads:

```
^(?!.*NO).*(YES)
```

or

```
^(?!.*themes).*(vendor)
```

as lookaheads can be of variable length. If `NO` is allowed to appear **after** `YES`, you have to check at every single character on the way to `YES`:

```
^((?!NO).)*(YES)
^((?!themes).)*(vendor)
```

**EDIT:** anubhava's solution is actually much neater. If you're ever in need of a single-regex solution you can use mine as a reference.

Comment: Your answer has positive lookaheads but I think you meant to use negative lookaheads - e.g. `^(?=.*NO).*(YES)` should read: `^(?!.*NO).*(YES)`. Also, you need / delimiters to define the boundaries of the NO and YES words.

Comment: @ridgerunner cheers, fixed the lookaheads. I'm not sure about the boundaries...the question seems a bit ambiguous as to whether `YES` and `NO` always have to be full directories or could be any substrings.

Comment: in this case they actually are full directories. But it could be useful/work as just string.

Answer (score 2):

Use it with a specific RewriteCond like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/NO/ [NC]
RewriteRule (^|/)YES(/.*|)$ - [F,L,NC]
```